# Sort a array of array of integers lexicographically

Tags: c, pointers, lexicographic

I'm using qsort() to sort a 2D array of integers lexiographically, each row being one input, but having problems with pointer arithmetic when traversing a row in the array.

Idea is to concatenate each column in one row into a string, and `strcmp` with other strings computed similarly from other rows.

Input is restricted to positive integers only. Some sort examples below,
`{1, 1, 10}` before `{1, 2, 0}`
`{3, 1, 5}` before `{3, 11, 5}`
`{1, 19, 2}` before `{1, 2, 1}`

```
#define COL_SIZE 3  

int cmp_func (const void *a, const void *b) {
    char str1[100], str2[100], temp[10];
    int i;
    const int **ia = (const int **)a;
    const int **ib = (const int **)b;

    printf("(a: %p), (b: %p)\n", a, b);
    str1[0] = '\0';
    str2[0] = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < COL_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("(ia+%d: %p), (ib+%d: %p)\n", i, (ia + i), i, (ib + i));
        sprintf(temp, "%d", (int)*(ia + i));
        strcat(str1, temp);

        sprintf(temp, "%d", (int)*(ib + i));
        strcat(str2, temp);
    }

    printf("a: %s, b:%s\n", str1, str2);
    return(strcmp(str1, str2));
}

int main (void) {
    int i, len;
    int A[][COL_SIZE] = {{1,2,3},
                         {1,1,5},
                         {1,0,1},
                         {1,2,1},
                         {1,2,0}};

    len = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
    printf("sizeof(int): %ld, sizeof(int *): %ld\n", sizeof(int), sizeof(int *));

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("Address of A[%d][0]: %p\n", i, A[i]);
    }

    qsort(A, len, COL_SIZE * sizeof(int *), cmp_func);
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the output:

```
sizeof(int): 4, sizeof(int *): 8  
Address of A[0][0]: 0x7fff58e9fb30  
Address of A[1][0]: 0x7fff58e9fb3c  
Address of A[2][0]: 0x7fff58e9fb48
Address of A[3][0]: 0x7fff58e9fb54  
Address of A[4][0]: 0x7fff58e9fb60  
(a: 0x7fff58e9fb30), (b: 0x7fff58e9fb48)  
(ia+0: 0x7fff58e9fb30), (ib+0: 0x7fff58e9fb48)  
(ia+1: 0x7fff58e9fb38), (ib+1: 0x7fff58e9fb50)  
(ia+2: 0x7fff58e9fb40), (ib+2: 0x7fff58e9fb58)  
a: 131, b:112  
(a: 0x7fff58e9fb48), (b: 0x7fff58e9fb60)  
(ia+0: 0x7fff58e9fb48), (ib+0: 0x7fff58e9fb60)  
(ia+1: 0x7fff58e9fb50), (ib+1: 0x7fff58e9fb68)  
(ia+2: 0x7fff58e9fb58), (ib+2: 0x7fff58e9fb70)  
Abort trap: 6
```

The pointer arithmetic for `*(ia + 1)` is causing the address in each iteration to jump by 8 `(sizeof(int *))` from `0x7fff58e9fb30` to `0x7fff58e9fb38`, whereas the next value in A[0] is stored at `0x7fff58e9fb34` (size of int).

How do I fix this so that I can get an offset of 4 instead of 8?

Comment: How do you want to sort the array? By rows or by all elements?

Comment: `int[3]` is not `int*`. `qsort(A, len, COL_SIZE * sizeof(int *), cmp_func);` --> `qsort(A, len, sizeof(*A),  cmp_func);`...

Comment: `const int **ia = (const int **)a;` --> `const int *ia = (const int *)a;`

Comment: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/jq2L8a)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow By rows.

Comment: There is no 2D array in the code shown. Something like `int **` is neither a 2D array, nor can it point to one. And casting a pointer to `int` is a really bad idea. If you want to print a pointer, use the correct conversion specifier.

Comment: @Olaf: You love that comment, but you're wrong this time.  The array `A` in `main()` is a 2D array.  There are all sorts of problems — some of them related to the use of `int **` — but there is a 2D array in the code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I would refrain using that comment if there were not so many questions which justify it:-} However, you are right, I overlooked that definition in `main`, just had a look at the function. Still, it seems that OP also confuses `int **` and a 2D array. Just not only from the name, but also from how they work.

Comment: Suppose that two rows in `A` are `{ 1, 91, 0 }` and `{ 1, 9, 10 }`.  Which of those rows should appear in the output first, and why?  Or, if that's a "doesn't matter", what about `{ 1, 91, 0 }` and `{ 1, 9, 11 }`; and `{ 1, 91, 0 }` and `{ 1, 9, 9 }`?  What is the 'lexicography' that you want the sort to obey?

Comment: @Olaf: I agree there's confusion related to trying to use `int **` where it cannot be used (because there isn't an array of pointers kicking around).  May I suggest rephrasing your comment a bit more carefully — delete the first and then add a new one.  I'll happily remove my comments.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Too much work for the night (it's 3:30am here;-) . Just let's leave the comments as they are; If you think different, tell me and we can clean the comments up, hoping OP gets the point from the answers.

Comment: @Olaf: that's fine if you want to leave it that way.  Good morning to you. (It's a bit late to say "Good night" — or is it?  That's a rhetorical question; I don't expect a response.)  I won't be offended if you end up flagging my relevant comments 'obsolete' or 'no longer constructive'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I se no reason to flag. And it's good night (soon ;-).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Could you explain why should `const int **` be changed to `const int *`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I want to see `{1, 9, 10}` before `{1, 91, 10}`. Because `9` is lexicographically smaller than `91`. Similarly for `{1, 2, 0}` and `{1, 19, 0}`, `{1, 19, 0}` should come before `{1, 2, 0}` since `19` is lexicographically smaller than `2`.

Comment: @adizone pointer `a` point to `int[3]`, not `int*`. pointer `ia` point to `int` as first elemet of `int[3]:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sorting an array of arrays, not an array of pointers.  Consequently, you need to clean up the code in the comparison function.  Also, the current incarnation of the comparator converts all the numbers to strings before doing any comparisons.  It is feasible and sensible to convert one number in each row at a time and stop when you find a difference, only converting the next number when the previous ones are the same.

This leads to the following code, which requires a C99 compiler or a C11 compiler with support for VLAs — variable length arrays — which are mandatory in C99 but optional in C11:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void dump_array(const char *tag, size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols, int A[n_rows][n_cols]);

enum { COLS  = 3 };

extern int cmp_func (const void *a, const void *b);

int cmp_func(const void *va, const void *vb)
{
    const int *a = *(const int (*)[COLS])va;
    const int *b = *(const int (*)[COLS])vb;

    for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++)
    {
        char str1[20], str2[20];
        sprintf(str1, "%d", a[i]);
        sprintf(str2, "%d", b[i]);
        int rc = strcmp(str1, str2);
        if (rc != 0)
            return rc;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int A[][COLS] =
    {
        { 1, 91, 10 },
        { 1,  9,  9 },
        { 1,  9, 11 },
        { 1,  1,  5 },
        { 1,  9, 10 },
        { 1,  0,  1 },
        { 1,  2,  3 },
        { 1, 91, 10 },
        { 1, 19,  0 },
        { 1, 91,  0 },
        { 1,  2,  0 },
        { 1,  2,  1 },
    };
    enum { ROWS = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]) };

    dump_array("Before", ROWS, COLS, A);
    qsort(A, ROWS, sizeof(A[0]), cmp_func);
    dump_array("After", ROWS, COLS, A);
    return 0;
}

static void dump_array(const char *tag, size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols, int A[n_rows][n_cols])
{
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    for (size_t r = 0; r < n_rows; r++)
    {
        const char *pad = "{";
        for (size_t c = 0; c < n_cols; c++)
        {
            printf("%s%3d", pad, A[r][c]);
            pad = ",";
        }
        puts(" }");
    }
}
```

The pointers passed to `cmp_func()` are pointers to arrays of `COLS` `int`s, or `int (*)[COLS]`; the assignments to `a` and `b` generate an array `int [COLS]`, which decays to an `int *`.  I usually use `v` as a prefix to the `const void *` arguments to a comparator, and remove the `v` for the working variables in the function.

The test data there includes test values from the commentary, and the output is:

```
Before:
{  1, 91, 10 }
{  1,  9,  9 }
{  1,  9, 11 }
{  1,  1,  5 }
{  1,  9, 10 }
{  1,  0,  1 }
{  1,  2,  3 }
{  1, 91, 10 }
{  1, 19,  0 }
{  1, 91,  0 }
{  1,  2,  0 }
{  1,  2,  1 }
After:
{  1,  0,  1 }
{  1,  1,  5 }
{  1, 19,  0 }
{  1,  2,  0 }
{  1,  2,  1 }
{  1,  2,  3 }
{  1,  9, 10 }
{  1,  9, 11 }
{  1,  9,  9 }
{  1, 91,  0 }
{  1, 91, 10 }
{  1, 91, 10 }
```

This code is similar to the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41529510/) by [RoadRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5238915/roadrunner), but primarily differs in the simpler, more efficient comparison function `cmp_func()` which does not necessarily convert all the numbers in each row to strings each time two rows are compared.  (In the sample data, the first value is always `1`, so at least two pairs of numbers are converted.  This is probably not normal, though.)

Comment: definitely a better approach :)

Comment: I also like the method of printing neatly using `tag` and `pad` :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that to concatenate integers that to compare rows is a good idea. In general the resulted strings can have different sizes. At least you have to add leading zeroes to each converted number that to align the strings and take into account signs of the integers.

Also you incorrectly dereference the void pointers.

And the call of the `qsort` is incorrect though it can work provided that `sizeof( int * )` is equal to `sizeof( int )`. You should write

```
qsort(A, len, sizeof( int[COL_SIZE] ), cmp_func);
```

I would write the program the following way

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define COL_SIZE 3

int cmp_rows(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const int *left  = *(const int(*)[COL_SIZE])a;
    const int *right = *(const int(*)[COL_SIZE])b;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < COL_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if ( left[i] < right[i]) return -1;
        else if (right[i] < left[i]) return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main( void )
{
    int A[][COL_SIZE] = 
    { 
        { 1,2,3 },
        { 1,1,5 },
        { 1,0,1 },
        { 1,2,1 },
        { 1,2,0 } 
    };

    qsort(A, sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A), sizeof(int[COL_SIZE]), cmp_rows);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < COL_SIZE; j++) printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 0 1
1 1 5
1 2 0
1 2 1
1 2 3
```

Comment: The comparison here is done based on the number at that index in the row. But it won't work for comparison between say `2` and `19`. For lexicographic sort, `19` should come before `2`.

Comment: @adizone It is not a lexicographical comparison of integer arrays.

Answer (score 1):

In these two lines:

```
const int **ia = (const int **)a;
const int **ib = (const int **)b;
```

This is incorrect, you only need one `*` pointer, as your are comparing elements in each row against other rows.

This needs to be changed to:

```
const int *ia = (const int *)a;
const int *ib = (const int *)b;
```

Furthermore, this line:

```
qsort(A, len, COL_SIZE * sizeof(int *), cmp_func);
```

needs to be changed to:

```
qsort(A, len, sizeof(*A), cmp_func);
```

The third parameter in [`qsort`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm) only requires a size of what it's comparing. In this case, size of each row, which can be expressed as `sizeof(*A)` or `sizeof(A[0])`.

Moreover, @Vlad from Moscow has a better approach which doesn't require concatenating strings.

If you still wish use a string approach, you can try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRSIZE 100
#define COL_SIZE 3

int cmp_func(const void *a, const void *b) {
    char str1[STRSIZE], str2[STRSIZE], temp[STRSIZE];
    size_t i;

    const int *row1 = (const int *)a;
    const int *row2 = (const int *)b;

    *str1 = '\0';
    *str2 = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < COL_SIZE; i++) {
        sprintf(temp, "%d", row1[i]);
        strcat(str1, temp);

        sprintf(temp, "%d", row2[i]);
        strcat(str2, temp);
    }  

    return strcmp(str1, str2);

}

void print_array(int A[][COL_SIZE], size_t len) {
    size_t row, col;

    for (row = 0; row < len; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < COL_SIZE; col++) {
            printf("%d ", A[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    size_t len;
    int A[][COL_SIZE] = {{1,2,0},
                         {1,19,0},
                         {1,19,0},
                         {1,19,0},
                         {1,2,0}};

    len = sizeof(A)/sizeof(*A);

    printf("\nBefore:\n");
    print_array(A, len);

    qsort(A, len, sizeof(*A), cmp_func);

    printf("\nAfter:\n");
    print_array(A, len);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before:
1 2 0
1 19 0
1 19 0
1 19 0
1 2 0

After:
1 19 0
1 19 0
1 19 0
1 2 0
1 2 0
```

Comment: This won't work if the input contains more than one digit. e.g., `{1, 2, 0}` and `{1, 19, 0}` should return `{1, 19, 0}` followed by `{1, 2, 0}` since `19` is lexicographically smaller than `2`.

Comment: Should be fine now. You should really put that test case in the question, to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Updated the question. I'm still unable to get my head around why `const int **` should be changed to `const int *`. The `cmp_func` arguments `*a` and `*b` should contain the address of first element of two rows of `A`?

Comment: if you call `cmp_func(*a, *b)`, then if you want to get the address of `a` and `b`, then you would need to do `&a` and `&b`, which will retrieve the first elements in each row, what you want to compare. In your function you are passing `cmp_func(**a, **b)`, and the addresses you are comparing are `&(*a)` and `&(*b)`, which would be the address of the first row, not the first number. I'm sorry if that is confusing, I'm not the best at explaining pointers :P

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
qsort(A, len, COL_SIZE * sizeof(int *), cmp_func);
```

You're telling qsort() to sort 'A', which has 'len'(5) items and each item is 3 *int's big.  But, 'A' is made up of int's, not *int's.

```
qsort(A, len, COL_SIZE * sizeof(int), cmp_func);
```

Give that a try.

Comment: 'Twould be better to use `qsort(A, len, sizeof(A[0]), cmp_func)`, would it not?